# Pointer as a structure members

Tags: c++

```
struct student{
string name;
int sNumber,*examGrade;
};

int main(){

int i,k,l;
cout<< "number of student in program:";
cin >>l;
cout<< "number of exam in program:";
cin >>k;
student stName[100], examNum[100];


for(int i=1;i<=l;i++){

    student stdnt;
    cout<<i<<".student name: ";
    cin>>stdnt.name;
    cout<<i<<".student number: ";
    cin>>stdnt.sNumber;
    stName[i] = stdnt;

    for(int j=1 ; j<=k; j++){

        student * test = new student();
        cout<<i<<". student"<<j<<".grade: ";
        cin>>*test->examGrade;
        examNum[j]= *test;

    }

    }


return 0;
}
```

I just started coding. What is the reason why the function could not be completed in the code I wrote?
How to assign value to a pointer struct?
I think I made a mistake accessing the pointer to the struct members.

Comment: `examGrade` is not initialized, `std::vector<int> examGrade;` would be simpler.

Comment: You declare `student.examGrade` as a pointer to `int`.  That's more or less fine.  But you do not assign any of those pointers a valid value.  If you want to use them to assign values to the pointed-to `int`s, then those `int`s must exist, and you must set the pointers to point to them.

Comment: Note that the number to specify in array declaration if the number of elements, so your program can deal with at most 99 students and exams, not 100.

Comment: Why do you want the `examGrade` member of `struct student` to be a pointer at all?    In any event, the pointer needs to be explicitly initialised so it actually points at an `int`.   For example, `test->examGrade = new int` before it is possible to read a value to `*test->examGrade`.      In general, creating a pointer does not magically create a pointee for that pointer.   `cin >> *test->examGrade` attempts to write to a non-existent `int`, so causes undefined behaviour.

Comment: Naming in `student stName[100], examNum[100];` is suspicious. Do you really want 200 `student`s.

Comment: Whereas short name like `i`, `j` are good enough name for iteration, `l`, `k` should be renamed to be meaningful, as for ex: `studientsCount`, `examsCount`.

Comment: C++ uses 0-indexing, not 1-indexing.

Comment: actually no. I just couldn't run the code when I did it without valuing the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used `test->examGrade` without initializing that. Assign valid pointer to that before dereferencing that.

```
    for(int j=1 ; j<=k; j++){

        student * test = new student();
        cout<<i<<". student"<<j<<".grade: ";
        test->examGrade = new int; // add this, for example
        cin>>*test->examGrade;
        examNum[j]= *test;

    }
```

Comment: BTW, `student * test` is useless (and actually leaks). and it should probably be `examGrade = new int [k];`.